# React Fetch When Param Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using a search bar an API call is made in the backend and redirects to my component page. Works well but I want to make a new fetch inside the component if the parameter in the url changes.

`http://localhost:3000/page/param1`

```
async componentDidMount() {

    var response = await fetch('/backend') // fetch data that was fetched from the backend
    var res = await response.json();
    var data = await res.data

    var fetched_param = await res.data.param // param appears in fetched data, so isolate it here
    var param = this.props.match.params.param // current param in url

    if (param !== fetched_param) {  // if param in url is different from the one that was fetched

        var newData = apiUrl + param + apiKey // create new api url           
        var response = await fetch(newData) // fetch new data
        ...
    }

    ... // use fetched data here

}
```

If the url param is changed and I use an `if` statement then I get some `undefined` errors when structuring the data since it doesn't get called asynchronously I think. How should I implement this? `componentDidUpdate`?

**Route**

`<Route exact path='/page/:param' component={Page}/>`

Error occurs when trying to set a variable further into `componentDidMount`

```
var res = response.data[0] //JSON data unavailable when going through if statement,
```

The data is available but it seems this error is thrown before the fetch returns the data.

Comment: Can you add your route declaration and if the route points to that component? Or is it a child component?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry new to React. My route is a simple app.post / app.get which fetches a url and then `res.send` to my component.

Comment: Something like this `<Route path="/page/:param" component={YourComponent} />`. Also, can you show us the exact error message and where it is raising the `undefined` error?

Comment: Thanks. See the edit. When the if statement is validated it fails to establish the data and variables further down throw undefined errors

Comment: Based on your edit, `var res = response.data[0]`, did you call `response.json()` like you did in the first call to fetch?

Comment: Yes everything works fine. But when I change the param in the url, I make the component fetch new data and that causes variables to be undefined because the component is already mounted

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new method `fetchData` that accepts url and call it in the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    // this is equal to:
    // const params = this.props.params
    const {match: { params }} = this.props;

    // You can store this in state
    const apiUrl = "your url"
    const apiKey = "your key"

    // I don't think this is necessary, but if you want
    // to fetch the data that is not based on param, this should be okay
    let data = await this.fetchData('/backend');

    if (params.param !== data.param) {
      data = await this.fetchData(apiUrl + params.param + apiKey)
    }

    // process fetched data
    this.processData(data)
  }

  componentDidUpdate = async prevProps => {
    const {match: { params }} = this.props;
    const newParam = params.param;
    const prevParam = prevProps.match.params.param;

    // Check if the param changed
    if (newParam !== prevParam) {
      // You can store this in state
      const apiUrl = "your url"
      const apiKey = "your key"
      const data = await this.fetchData()

      // process fetched data
      this.processData(data)
    }
  };

  fetchData = async url => {
    const response = await fetch(url); // fetch data that was fetched from the backend
    const jsonRes = await response.json();
    return jsonRes.data;
  };

  processData = (data) => {
    // process your data here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great! Trying it now. It works well but it seems like I can't fetch from the front end. I guess I need to route the fetch request through the backend?